# setting div to row but nothing happens

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, razor-components

I am trying to make the three items in the top_three div to be displayed in a row but when I set it to row nothing happens, but if I set the .scoreboard to row then I get the row, but I don't want the .restplaces div to be in a row I want it to be displayed underneath, I really don't understand why it's not working.
I use a css file with a Razor component:

Razor component:

```
@if (Teams is not null)
{
<div class="confetti_container">

    <div class="confetti"></div>
    **(There are like 20 more of this div but i don't wanna clutter this here)**

</div>
<div class="scoreboard">
    @do
    {
        _place++;
        var allteams = Teams.Where(team => team.TeamPoints == 
        Teams[0].TeamPoints).ToList();


        foreach (var team in allteams)
        {
            <div class="top_three">
                @if (_place == 2)
                {
                    <div class="secondplace">
                        <div class="secondplaceimg"></div>
                        <h1>@team.TeamName</h1>
                    </div>

                }
                @if (_place == 1)
                {
                    <div class="firstplace">
                        <div class="firstplaceimg"></div>
                        <h1>@team.TeamName</h1>
                    </div>
                }
                @if (_place == 3)
                {
                    <div class="thirdplace">
                        <div class="thirdplaceimg"></div>
                        <h1>@team.TeamName</h1>
                    </div>
                }

            </div>
            @if (_place > 3)
            {

                <div class="restplaces">
                    <p>@_place. @team.TeamName</p>
                </div>
            }


            Teams.Remove(team);
        }
        if (Teams.Count == 0)
        {
            _scoreboardCreated = true;
        }
    } while (_scoreboardCreated == false);

</div>

 }
 else if (_deleted is true)
 {
    <h1>Session expired</h1>
 }
 else
 {
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  }
```

And here the CSS-file (I use a div with a background-image because the img htmltag just doesn't seem to load the image).

```
.scoreboard {
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
align-items: center;
 }
 .top_three {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
 }

 .firstplace {
  padding: 8vh 5vw 5vh 5vw;
 }

  .firstplaceimg {
  background-image: url("/images/Firstplace.png");
  height: 340px;
  width: 315px;
  }

  .secondplace {
  padding: 15vh 5vw 5vh 5vw;
  }

  .secondplaceimg {
  background-image: url("/images/Secondplace.png");
  height: 270px;
  width: 250px;
  }

  .thirdplace {
  padding: 28vh 5vw 8vh 5vw;
  }

  .thirdplaceimg {
  background-image: url("/images/Thirdplace.png");
  height: 170px;
  width: 155px;
 }

.restplaces {
display:flex;
margin: 0vh 0vw 5vh 3vw;
background-color: #bd8379;
width: 10vw;
border-radius: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .30);
}
/*CONFETTI*/
.confetti_container {
min-height: 70vh;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 60px;
position: absolute;
width: 95%;
}

.confetti {
background: rgb(166,124,0);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(166,124,0,1) 0%, rgba(191,155,48,1) 10%, 
rgba(255,191,0,1) 20%, rgba(255,207,64,1) 30%, rgba(255,220,115,1) 40%, 
rgba(255,216,99,1) 
50%, rgba(255,220,115,1) 60%, rgba(255,207,64,1) 70%, rgba(255,191,0,1) 80%, 
rgba(191,155,48,1) 90%, rgba(166,124,0,1) 100%);
border: 1px solid #A57C01;
position: absolute;
display: flex;
width: 10px;
height: 25px;
top: -100px;
}

.confetti:nth-child(1) {
    animation: fall 2.5s linear infinite;
    left: 10%;
}
```

It feels like I'm just missing a tiny detail

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `display: inline-block;` to make the divs in one row,change the css of `scoreboard` and `top_three` like this:

```
.scoreboard {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.top_three {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

result:
[image]